# Pass parameter to lambda expression - Java

Tags: java, lambda, hashmap

My program requires that I accept a user input and, based on this input, a method is to be carried out. My basic thoughts are described well by the following question/answer:

[How to call a method stored in a HashMap? (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480334/how-to-call-a-method-stored-in-a-hashmap-java)

To do this, I have created an array of lambda expressions:

```
public final Runnable[] userCommandMethods = {

        () -> userCommand1(),
        () -> userCommand2(),
    };
```

And an array of keys:

```
public final String[] userCommandKeys = {

        commandKey1,
        commandKey2,
    };
```

Which are joined to create a HashMap using the following method:

```
public Map<String, Runnable> mapArrays (String[] array1, Runnable[] array2) {

        Map<String, Runnable> mappedArrays = new HashMap<String, Runnable>();

        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i ++) {

            mappedArrays.put(array1[i], array2[i]);
        }
        return mappedArrays;
    }
```

When I attempt to run a method by using `myHashMap.get(userInput).run();` it works perfectly, provided none of the methods in `userCommandMethods` require input parameters.

**My question:**

How would I pass an input parameter (specifically a Hash Map) into the methods contained within `userCommandMethods`?

When the `userCommand1()` method takes an input parameter, but the lambda expression does not, I get the following error:

> The method userCommand1(Map<String, String>) in the type ProgramCommands is not applicable for the arguments ()

However, when I do pass a parameter to the method, it states that it cannot be resolved to a variable.

**Edit: to elaborate:**

When the `userCommand1()` method takes no arguments:

```
public void userCommand1 () {

      // Do some stuff
}
```

It works perfectly fine. However, I am unsure how to use the lambda expressions if the method does take an input parameter:

```
public void userCommand1 (Map<String, String> myMap) {

      // Do some stuff
}
```

Comment: When do you want to pass the parameters? Do all the methods in the map take the same type and number of parameters? You said "However, when I do pass a parameter to the method..." how exactly did you do this?

Comment: I would like to pass the parameters when the method is called. In other words, when I get the method from the map using the user input. Yes, all methods that require an input do take the same input parameter (however, some take none). When I say I 'pass the parameter to the method', I mean that the actual method has been created to require an input, as opposed to leaving the () braces empty.

Comment: Have edited to clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to choose another functional interface (not `Runnable`).

For example, if your methods all take a `String` parameter, you should use [`Consumer<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html). If they take a `String` and an `int`, then you should use [`BiConsumer<String, Integer>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html). If your methods need more than 2 parameters, you need to create your own functional interface. For an example, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63589660/5133585).

```
// use a list instead of an array, because arrays don't work well with generic types 
public final List<Consumer<String>> userCommandMethods = List.of(
    x -> userCommand1(x),
    x -> userCommand2() // it's fine if the method takes fewer parameters
);
```

Instead of `run`, you would call `accept`, which is what `Consumer` and `BiConsumer`'s single abstraction method is called.

Note that you can also use the method reference syntax. If `userCommand1` is static, `x -> userCommand1(x)` can be rewritten as `SomeClass::userCommand1` where `SomeClass` is the enclosing class of `userCommand1`. If `userCommand1` is non static, it can be rewritten as `this::userCommand1`.

You don't need to build the map from two arrays. You can use [`ofEntries`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#ofEntries-java.util.Map.Entry...-) and [`entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entry-K-V-) to write the entries inline.

```
private final Map<String, Consumer<String>> someMap = Map.ofEntries(
    Map.entry("foo", SomeClass::userCommand1),
    Map.entry("bar", SomeClass::userCommand2),
    Map.entry("baz", SomeClass::userCommand3),
    // and so on
)
```

Comment: So, if I were to pass a map object as a parameter, would I simply change ```Runnable[]``` to ```Consumer<Map<String, String>>[]```? Or would this be an example of creating my own interface? In my mind, this is still a single input parameter, but I am getting an error stating > Cannot create a generic array of Consumer<Map<String,String>>

Comment: @ChaddRobertson Yes, that's a single parameter.

Comment: @ChaddRobertson Sorry, I forgot that creating arrays of generic types is a bit of a pain. In any case, you should be using the way I showed at the end - using `Map.entry` and `Map.of`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Runnable interface that takes no argument on input:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Runnable {
    public abstract void run();
}
```

Instead, you can define your custom interface and consume it.

As a simple example:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface RunnableWithArg {    
    void apply(String t) throws RuntimeException;    
}
```

And implementation may look like:

```
public class RunnableTest {

    //also fine:
    //public final RunnableWithArg[] userCommandMethods = { t -> this.userCommand1(t), t -> this.userCommand2(t) };
    
    public final RunnableWithArg[] userCommandMethods = { this::userCommand1, this::userCommand2 };

    public String commandKey1 = "commandKey1";
    public String commandKey2 = "commandKey2";

    public final String[] userCommandKeys = { commandKey1, commandKey2, };

    public Map<String, RunnableWithArg> mapArrays(String[] array1, RunnableWithArg[] array2) {

        Map<String, RunnableWithArg> mappedArrays = new HashMap<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {

            mappedArrays.put(array1[i], array2[i]);
        }
        return mappedArrays;
    }

    public void userCommand1(String data) {
        System.out.println("userCommand1 called with " + data);
    }

    public void userCommand2(String data) {
        System.out.println("userCommand2 called with " + data);
    }
    
    public void test()
    {
        var fncMap = mapArrays(userCommandKeys, userCommandMethods);
        
        for(String key: fncMap.keySet())
        {
            var fnc = fncMap.get(key);
            fnc.apply(key);
        }
    }
}
```

And of course you can also define some generic types of "@FunctionalInterface" like this, so you can use it for both taking input and returning some output of generic types:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface AbcFunction<T, R> {

    R apply(T t) throws AbcException;

    static <T> Function<T, T> identity() {
        return t -> t;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you are thinking of?

```
interface Command<T> {
   public void run(T arg);
}

class SayHelloCommand implements Command<String>{
   public void run(String name){
      System.out.println("hello " + name);
   }
}

class CountCommand implements Command<Integer>{
   public void run(Integer limit){
      for(int i=0; i<=limit; i++)
        System.out.println(i);
   }
}

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Command[] commands = new Command[3];
        commands[0] = new SayHelloCommand();
        commands[1] = new CountCommand();
        
        commands[0].run("Joe");
        commands[1].run(5);
    }
}
```